# Center translateY animation in IE

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I can't seem to center this animation in IE. It is fine across all other browsers but in IE it is off to the right. Have tried translate(-50%, -50%), but still get the same result. If anyone can help me figure this out I would be greatly appreciative. I have been looking for a solution for a while but have had no luck. Seems like it should be something simple.

[https://jsfiddle.net/d0jmeyu7/2/][1]

```
<style>
.container {
position: absolute;
background-color: skyblue;
height: 500px;
width: 500px;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
display: -webkit-flexbox;
display: -moz-flexbox;
display: -o-flexbox;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-ms-flex-pack: center;
-webkit-flex-pack: center;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
z-index: 1;
border: 2px solid red;
}

.container > div {
position: absolute;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: red;
pointer-events: none;
-webkit-animation: animation 3s forwards;
-moz-animation: animation 3s forwards;
-ms-animation: animation 3s forwards;
-o-animation: animation 3s forwards;
animation: animation 3s forwards;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
z-index: 3;
border: 2px solid red;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animation {
0% {
transform: translateY(0px);
}
100% {
transform: translateY(-40%);
}
}

@-moz-keyframes animation {
0% {
transform: translateY(0px);
}
100% {
transform: translateY(-40%);
}
}

@-o-keyframes animation {
0% {
transform: translateY(0px);
}
100% {
transform: translateY(-40%);
}
}

@keyframes animation {
0% {
transform: translateY(0px);
}
100% {
transform: translateY(-40%);
}
}
</style>

<div class="container">
<div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you combine Flexbox and absolute positioned flex items, you get an inconsistent behavior cross browsers, as seen in this case, where IE (and Safari) will not center the inner `div`.

By simply remove `position: absolute` from the `.container > div` rule it will work.

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: skyblue;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flexbox;
  display: -o-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-flex-pack: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.container > div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-animation: animation 3s forwards;
  -moz-animation: animation 3s forwards;
  -ms-animation: animation 3s forwards;
  -o-animation: animation 3s forwards;
  animation: animation 3s forwards;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  z-index: 3;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animation {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateY(-40%);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes animation {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateY(-40%);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes animation {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateY(-40%);
  }
}

@keyframes animation {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateY(-40%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```